# How to get date of upcoming notification?

Tags: ios, swift, unusernotificationcenter

I can get the next notification with the following code:

```swift
let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
center.getPendingNotificationRequests { (notifications) in
    let pendingNotifications : [UNNotificationRequest] = notifications
    let notification = pendingNotifications[0]
    let trigger = notification.trigger
    let content = notification.content
}
```

`trigger` gets me:

```
<UNCalendarNotificationTrigger: 0x6000004319e0; dateComponents: <NSDateComponents: 0x60000014f570>
    Hour: 16
    Minute: 10
    Second: 0, repeats: YES>
```

But I can't call `trigger.dateComponents`

How do I get this date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use `dateComponents` of the `UNCalendarNotificationTrigger`. try using `notification.fireDate` to retrieve that.

More info on Apple Developer Documentation: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/uncalendarnotificationtrigger

Answer (score 8):

You need to be careful when using nextTriggerDate().  It might be providing a date that you are not expecting.

See the follow [Does UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger nextTriggerDate() give the wrong date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40411812/does-untimeintervalnotificationtrigger-nexttriggerdate-give-the-wrong-date).

I've been able to confirm that this is happening when using a time interval trigger, this might be affect calendar triggers as well.

Though the date nextTriggerDate() provides might not be what you are expecting, the schedule by the OS is actually correct.

It might be helpful for you to attach some date related data in the userInfo property of the notification content (UNNotificationContent).

```
let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
content.title = "Title"
content.body = "This is a test"
content.sound = UNNotificationSound.default()
content.userInfo = ["date" : Date()]
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to cast UNNotificationTrigger to `UNCalendarNotificationTrigger` and get its [nextTriggerDate](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/uncalendarnotificationtrigger/1649775-nexttriggerdate).

```
if let calendarNotificationTrigger = notifications.first?.trigger as? UNCalendarNotificationTrigger, 
    let nextTriggerDate = calendarNotificationTrigger.nextTriggerDate() {
    print(nextTriggerDate)  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To get the next notification you need to get the dates for all the requests and select the lowest:

```
UNUserNotificationCenter.current().getPendingNotificationRequests {
    (requests) in
    var nextTriggerDates: [Date] = []
    for request in requests {
        if let trigger = request.trigger as? UNCalendarNotificationTrigger,
            let triggerDate = trigger.nextTriggerDate(){
            nextTriggerDates.append(triggerDate)
        }
    }
    if let nextTriggerDate = nextTriggerDates.min() {
        print(nextTriggerDate)
    }
}
```